# Smarty: multidimensional array key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, smarty

I found in stack solution how to view multidimensional array in Smarty

```
{foreach from=$myArr key=key item=item}
    <h2>{$key}</h2>
    {foreach from=$item item=i}
        {$i} <br />
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

But in 2nd foreach I can't gey key value (index), how to do it?
I tryed

```
{foreach from=$myArr key=key item=item}
        <h2>{$key}</h2>
        {foreach from=$item key=k item=i}
            {$i} <br />
            {$k} <br />
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
```

But it's not working

Comment: What does this output? Show the output page source.  Is `$myArr` actually multi-dimensional?

Comment: ok, sorry i had bug preparing this array. THx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @key or @index on your current var.

```
{$i@key}
{$i@index}
```